# OpenApi Not Working with Spring Boot Gradle Project

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, swagger, openapi

I am trying to add OpenApi to my Spring Boot Gradle project. I've added the OpenAPI plugin to my `build.gradle` file, but when I start my app, none of the URLs that are supposed to make documentation seem to get generated.

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id "org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin" version "1.6.0"
}

group = 'com.sampleproject'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.servlet.context-path=/sample-service
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui-custom.html
```

I have tried building and running my project with:

- `./gradlew clean build` followed by `java -jar build/libs/name-of-jar-file.jar`
- `./gradlew clean generateOpenApiDocs`

Links that I've been using:

- https://springdoc.org/v2/#gradle-plugin
- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-gradle-plugin

Both links say to add the plugin, which I did. When my app is running, I try going to `http://localhost:8080/sample-service/api-docs` and `http://localhost:8080/sample-service/swagger-ui-custom.html`, and both give me the standard spring white label error page.

I have two controller classes in my application, and all endpoints work fine when my app is running.

What am I missing or doing wrong in order to get OpenAPI to work with my Spring Boot Gradle application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to enable swagger UI, you will need to add the plugin of

```
implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-ui', version: '1.6.14'
```

Adding this to build.gradle dependencies will solve your problem. I hope this helps.

Comment: Did not worked on me.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like they changed it again. Add

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.1.0'
```

OR for Gradle Kotlin:

```kotlin
implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.1.0")
```

to the dependencies.

(... and remove any older openapi related entries, also the openapi-gradle-plugin from plugin section!)